# C#: Is it right to use Interlocked to count the number of calls of a delegate?

Tags: c#, .net-core, concurrency, locking, interlocked-increment

I am playing around with `Interlocked.Increment` and was wondering which of the call counter impl. below (to basically get the number of call of a given delegate) is doing its job properly (ie. thread-safe) in a highly concurrent environment.

```cs
public interface ICallCounter<in TInput, out TOutput>
{
    public TOutput Invoke(TInput input);
    public int Count { get; }
}
public class InterlockedPreCallCounter<TInput, TOutput> : ICallCounter<TInput, TOutput>
{
    private readonly Func<TInput, TOutput> _func;
    private int _count;
    public int Count => _count;

    public InterlockedPreCallCounter(Func<TInput, TOutput> func) => _func = func;

    public TOutput Invoke(TInput input)
    {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref _count);
        // What if there is an interruption / crash at some point here?
        return _func(input);
    }

}
public class InterlockedPostCallCounter<TInput, TOutput>
{
    private readonly Func<TInput, TOutput> _func;
    private int _count;
    public int Count => _count;
    public InterlockedPostCallCounter(Func<TInput, TOutput> func) => _func = func;

    public TOutput Invoke(TInput input)
    {
        var result = _func(input);
        Interlocked.Increment(ref _count);
        return result;
    }
}
public class LockCallCounter<TInput, TOutput> : ICallCounter<TInput, TOutput>
{
    private readonly Func<TInput, TOutput> _func;
    public int Count { get; private set; }
    private readonly object _syncRoot = new object();

    public LockCallCounter(Func<TInput, TOutput> func) => _func = func;

    public TOutput Invoke(TInput input)
    {
        lock (_syncRoot)
        {
            var result = _func(input);
            Count++;
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It depends what you're trying to count. The pre-call implementation counts the number of times `Invoke` is called, regardless of if it fails, the post-call implementation counts the number of successful calls to `Invoke`. Tjhe `LockCall` implementation is the same as your post-call version except that it serializes all calls to `_func`

Comment: @Sean Maybe it should have been phrased, is there by any chance the possibility of the program crashing and then the thrown exception is caught and hence which one is then "sturdiest" impl.

Comment: "Tjhe LockCall implementation is the same as your post-call version except that it serializes all calls to _func" wdym?

Comment: It depends what you're trying to measure. They're all equally sturdy, but each does something different to the others.

Comment: In `LockCall` only one thread at a time can call `Invoke` as you've got a lock in it. In you other implementation multiple threads can call it.

Comment: Wasn't sure what you meant by serializing, thanks! If say, we measure sturdiness by having the lowest probability count the probability of incident that might happen between the `Interlocked.Increment` and the actual (be it post / pre) delegate call?
Ok gotcha kinda makes sense now.

Comment: What does the `Count` property represents? 1. The number of times the `Invoke` method has started? 2. The number of times the `Invoke` method has completed? 3. The number of times the `Invoke` method has completed successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All methods are completely thread-safe, with respect to `_count`.

However, this will increment `_count` irrespective as to whether `_func` throws an exception:

```
Interlocked.Increment(ref _count);
return _func(input);
```

This will increment `_count` only if `_func` does not throw an exception.

```
var result = _func(input);
Interlocked.Increment(ref _count);
return result;
```

And this will do the same as the above, but with poorer performance in a multi-threaded environment, particularly because only one thread will be able to call `_func` at any one time:

```
lock (_syncRoot)
{
    var result = _func(input);
    Count++;
    return result;
}
```

Which you choose depends on what you are trying to measure.